# Select rows using values provided in WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a list of ids -

```
58997,
59186,
59647,
59811,
60005,
60468,
60469,
60655,
60656,
60868,
61448,
61584,
61585,
61787.
```

Each ID represent a record in a table. The record also contains a date.

How can I select rows which have the above ids BUT with a date greater than or equal to DATE.

I am using the following query but it returns all the rows having the above mentioned ids.

```
SELECT id 
FROM customer
WHERE date >= 1481756400 AND
      id IN (58997,59186,59647,59811,60005,60468,60469,60655,60656,
60868,61448,61584,61585,61787)
```

Comment: Your query looks correct. Change your `SELECT id` to `SELECT id, date` and you will see the corresponding date values so you can check them.

Comment: Your query should do what you want, assuming that your date constant is in the same format as the date.  You might want to include sample data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  A `date` in the database is not stored using Unix style formats.  Perhaps you simply want to convert the constant to a date format:

```
SELECT id 
FROM customer
WHERE date >= from_unixtime(1481756400) AND
      id IN (58997,59186,59647,59811,60005,60468,60469,60655,60656,
60868,61448,61584,61585,61787);
```